# How to make dialog elments collapsible?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

Is there any way to make DialogGroup elements collapsible through X++?

I've been looking at MSDN and going through the class but I don't seem to find something that would be useful.

Another developer has added two groups to the dialog that is displayed when creating a payment proposal (CustVendPaymJournal_Vend Class) and the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons are no longer displayed on smaller resolutions (1024x768).

My approach is to make some of the groups collapsible to enable the dialog to display such buttons.

Comment: found a solution, will post it in 6 hours because I'm not allowed to do so until then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.

After looking at the MSDN for quite longer than I would have wanted to, I found the solution:

Once the DialogGroup is created
`dialogGroupProposalType = dialog.addGroup("@SYS88520");`

There is a method called `frameOptionButton()` available, which receives a FormFrameOptionButton ennumeration value as parameter.

`dialogGroupProposalType.frameOptionButton(FormFrameOptionButton::Hide);`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa845161(v=ax.50).aspx#F

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa627673(v=ax.50).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa627673(v=ax.50).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa592526(v=ax.50).aspx

Comment: Or `dialog.addGroup("@SYS88520").frameOptionButton(FormFrameOptionButton::Hide);`

Comment: In case anyone else needs it, I just figured out that dialogGroup.optionValue(0) will allow you to collapse the group.