# DialogTabPage object does not have method 'frameType'

Tags: dialog, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta

This is related to my question posted here:

[How to make dialog elments collapsible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463319/collapsible-elements-on-ax-2009-dialog-custvendpaymjournal-custvendpaymjourna)

Another developer has added two groups to the dialog that is displayed when creating a payment proposal (CustVendPaymJournal_Vend Class) and the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons are no longer displayed on smaller resolutions (1024x768).

To overcome this I am trying to group some dialog elements in DialogTabPage tabs. However I haven't had any success in my attempts.

This is what I have in the first couple lines of code in the dialog() method for CustVendCreatePaymJournal_Vend

```
public Object dialog()
{
    LedgerJournalType   ledgerJournalType;
    DialogTabPage       tab;
    super();
    tab = dialog.addTabPage("First tab");
}
```

I keep on receiving this error anywhere I try to add a tab in the dialog. I have tried to put it on CustVendPaymJournal (from which CustVendPaymJournal_Vend is inherited) also, but to no avail.

```
DialogTabPage object does not have method 'frameType'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dialog = super();
tab = dialog.addTabPage("First tab");
```

Comment: Thank you for answering @JanBKjeldsen, but I'm affraid it did not make any difference.